# Record type, Collection and Bulk collect at the same time in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

***I am facing a challenge in implementing a scenario in code.
I am trying to use record type, collections and bulk collect at the same time during a proof of concept. But I am unable to and I am getting errors.
I don't know how to pass the bulk collect argument as an input parameter to the proc which I had created in the package below...***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE poc1
AS
   TYPE poc_rectype IS RECORD
   (
      id     VARCHAR2 (20),
      name   VARCHAR2 (20)
   );
   PROCEDURE poc1_prc (poc_rec1 IN poc_rectype);
END poc1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poc1
AS
   PROCEDURE poc1_prc (poc_rec1 IN poc_rectype)
   IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. poc_rec1.COUNT
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('poc_rec1' || poc_rec1.COUNT);
      END LOOP;

*-- i want to print the records passed from the execution script here 
-- later i want to do some insertion in some table..*

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('executed');
   END poc1_prc;
END poc1;
```

Here I am trying to pass only one record for now..
But, I wish to pass a collection of records and print it out or do some insertion in the package containing the procedure above.

```
/* execution script for the above package*/
DECLARE
   l_rec_type   poc1.poc_rectype;
BEGIN
   SELECT (SELECT 100, 'Jack' FROM DUAL)
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_rec_type
     FROM DUAL;
   poc1.poc1_prc (l_rec_type);
END;
```

***Please could someone help me on implementing this POC.
I tried everything. but i am feeling helpless***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you were missing a nested table to hold the values. You had a record type and a record variable. But a record variable can only hold a single row of data. To hold multiple rows of data, you need a record type, a nested table, and a nested table variable.

Here's the package to contain the types and process the data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE poc1
AS
   TYPE poc_rectype IS RECORD
   (
      id     VARCHAR2 (20),
      name   VARCHAR2 (20)
   );
   TYPE poc_tab is table of poc_rectype;
   PROCEDURE poc1_prc (poc_recs IN poc_tab);
END poc1;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poc1
AS
   PROCEDURE poc1_prc (poc_recs IN poc_tab)
   IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. poc_recs.COUNT
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('poc_recs.id: ' || poc_recs(i).id);
      END LOOP;
   END poc1_prc;
END poc1;
/
```

Here's an anonymous block that populates the nested table variable and passes it to the collection for processing:

```
DECLARE
   l_pocs   poc1.poc_tab;
BEGIN
   SELECT id, name
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_pocs
   FROM
   (
      SELECT 100 id, 'Jack' name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 101 id, 'Jill' name FROM DUAL
   );

   poc1.poc1_prc(l_pocs);
END;
/
Output:
-------
poc_recs.id: 100
poc_recs.id: 101
```

Since you tagged the question with 10g, you might need to add an extra step, and create the record type and nested table as separate variables. Older versions of Oracle couldn't always convert from SQL to PL/SQL types.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Heller.. Appreciate your help...  Please keep up your good work

Comment: To print out the output... should we use set serveroutput in the execution script or shall we store the  pass the output as an **out parameter** from the package to the execution script..

Comment: I'd recommend passing the output or returning it from a function. Let the last step of the process handle the output. Separating the processing from the display might help later.  For example if you run into problems where certain environments can't handle large amounts of DBMS_OUTPUT and you might need to rethink how to show the data.

Comment: Super... Jon... Thank you... :)

Comment: Hi Jon. Hope you are doing well.... I was trying to use DML 'UPDATE' instead of printing . But I am facing issues doing so.. Wont we able to do DML using the below Syntax..... *** CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY poc1
AS
   PROCEDURE poc1_prc (poc_recs IN poc_tab)
   IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. poc_recs.COUNT
      LOOP
         update temp set
   temp_name= poc_recs(i).name
   where temp_id = temp_id= poc_recs(i).id
   
      END LOOP;
   END poc1_prc;
END poc1;
/ ***

Comment: @jack I think that code just has some syntax errors. There's a missing `;` after `id`, and there is an extra `temp_id= `. After those changes, the package built and ran correctly for me. If you're still having problems, you might need to add more details to make a fully reproducible test case.

Comment: Hi Jon.. hope you are doing well.. I am facing another issue... Could you please guide me   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534423/could-type-be-used-with-object-type-is-it-possible-because-i-am-getting-error