# Could %type be used with Object type? Is it possible because I am getting error while trying to do so

Tags: oracle, types, oracle11g

I am trying to use %type with object type

for eg ,

### ***Method 1:***

```
  CREATE TYPE emp_object AS OBJECT(
    i_Emp_id Employee_table.emp_id%type,
    i_Emp_name  Employee_table.emp_name%type
    i_salary  Employee.salary%type);
```

**But I am unable to create object type as in the method 1...**

I am able to create object type by using method 2, but this has some functionality issue when I use it in my application as mentioned below..

### ***Method 2:***

```
 CREATE TYPE emp_object AS OBJECT( i_Emp_id number, i_Emp_name  varchar2(10), i_Salary Number(13,9));
```

*The problem which i am facing with the second method is that, when ever I change the precision of the data type in Salary column in the table, I have to change drop the object type and recreate it. Also I have to change the code in the API and UI.. This could be surely avoided if I can use the %type while creating the object type. But I am unable to do so because Oracle throws error. Is there a way to apply %type for object type columns.. Please help me...I tried everything but I am facing this blocker for along time...*

Comment: @Jon Heller
Please could you help Jon

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know there's no way to use %TYPE in SQL. I'm not sure why the feature isn't supported; these kind of questions come up frequently, and Oracle already supports changing type dependencies through [type evolution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adobj/type-evolution.html#GUID-AD083363-701A-4CE4-8795-C55D7EBCCB47). Maybe a future version will support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, Oracle does not support %TYPE for object attributes - because %TYPE is PL/SQL syntax, not SQL.

Why not just declare i_salary as NUMBER with no precision and scale?

Comment: Hi Tony... thank you for your response.. I can use i_salary as Number in object type but, in case we need a change from Number to Number (13,9) we have to change it every where, like in api and UI too.. Just to shorten this approach and to avoid frequent change in code everywhere, I needed to know whether %TYPE could be applied in object type..